# Maxima batch mode quits before plotting

Tags: maxima

I want to look at plots of Maxima when it's running with batch mode. However, Maxima quits too fast. Is there any way to "persist" like gnuplot?

My environment is: Ubuntu 14.04 64bit, Maxima 5.32.1.

*sin.max*

```
plot2d(sin(x),[x,0,2*%pi]);
```

Terminal:

```
$ maxima -b sin.max # It ends too fast!
```

Comment: Where is the connection to [tag:batch-file]?? please correct the tags appropriately!

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused batch-file and "batch processing." Thank you for notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make Maxima pause until key-press with a call to `readline()`:

*sin.max*

```maxima
plot2d(sin(x), [x,0,2*%pi]);
readline(?\*standard\-input\*);
```